# Why my code is printing blueberries twice ? whats wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, python-3.7

```
b_strings = [ ]
L = [['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges', 'blueberries', 'lemons'], ['carrots', 'peas', 'cucumbers', 'green beans'], ['root beer', 'smoothies', 'cranberry juice']]
for x in L:
    for y in x:
        for z in y:
            if z == 'b':
                b_strings.append(y)

print(b_strings)
```

Below, we have provided a list of lists named L. Use nested iteration to save every string containing “b” into a new list named b_strings.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, that's exactly what is supposed to happen considering your code. Did you expect something else? We can't know. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: `for z in y:` iterates chars in string and "blueberries" has two "b" in it

Comment: Because blueberries has two 'b' letters

Answer (score 2):

Because there are two `b` in `blueberries`. So `if z == 'b':` will succeed twice, and it will append the word to `b_strings` each time.

If you only want to do it once, you can break out of the loop.

```
for x in L:
    for y in x:
        for z in y:
            if z == 'b':
                b_strings.append(y)
                break
```

Or you can use the `in` operator to check for the letter, instead of looping.

```
for x in L:
    for y in x:
        if 'b' in y:
            b_strings.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

or with list comprehension

```
b_strings = [ ]

b_strings = [value for row in liste for value in row if "b" in value]
```